# Creating a static library with the Visual C++ 6 compiler instead of a dynamic library (DLL)

Tags: visual-c++

I am able to create a DLL, but I want it to compile into a .lib file using Visual C++ 6 (commmad line).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'Win32 Static Library' project for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project you have the option to create a Win32 Static Library.

Having just created one to check the options I see that the tabs on the project settings dialog are different to those for DLL project.

Your best bet is to create a new project and copy the source files across. If you need the code to compile into both then you'll need to create the projects in the same directory (but with different names) or link the source from one directory to the other.